# How to find words relevances in a single document?

Tags: python, nltk, cpu-word, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I want to find the relevance of some words (like economy, technology) in a single document.

The document has around 30 pages, the idea is to extract all text and determine words relevances for this document.

I know that TF-IDF is used in a group of document, but is it possible to use TF-IDF to solve this problem? If not, how can I do this in Python?

Comment: You could build an IDF vector from a bigger collection of decuments. You need *something* to compare against to decide a baseline.

Comment: The `IDF` part of TF-IDF renders this approach counter-intuitive, since it assumes that high frequency in a *single* document, but low frequency across documents to be of high importance. It might be a bit better to just consider term frequency and drop out stop-words

Comment: Perhaps using a summarization algorithm would work?

Answer (score 0):

Using NLTK and one of its builtin corpora, you can make some estimates on how "relevant" a word is:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import log
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import brown

toks = word_tokenize(open('document.txt').read().lower())
tf = Counter(toks)
freqs = Counter(w.lower() for w in brown.words())
n = len(brown.words())
for word in tf:
    tf[word] *= log(n / (freqs[word] + 1))**2    
for word, score in tf.most_common(10):
    print('%8.2f %s' % (score, word))
```

Change `document.txt` to the name of your document and the script will output the ten most "relevant" words in it.